# Fading Alert boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on some *fade out alert boxes* where once the `fa-close` is clicked, it will then fade out **and then** slide the rest of the alerts/content upwards.

Here's what I've got:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'div.alert > i', function() {
    var trg = $(this);
    var parent = trg.parent();

    parent.animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 250, function() {
      parent.animate({
        'padding-top': 0,
        'padding-bottom': 0,
        height: 0
      }, 125, function() {
        parent.remove();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
div.alert {
  width: 940px;
  margin: auto auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: solid 1px #DDD;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
div.alert > a,
div.alert > p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 600;
}
div.alert > i {
  float: right;
  line-height: 17px;
}
div.alert > i:hover {
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div.alert.alert-success > *,
div.alert.alert-info > *,
div.alert.alert-warning > *,
div.alert.alert-danger > *,
div.alert.alert-posion > * {
  color: #FFF;
}
div.alert.alert-success > i:hover,
div.alert.alert-info > i:hover,
div.alert.alert-warning > i:hover,
div.alert.alert-danger > i:hover,
div.alert.alert-posion > i:hover {
  color: #F0F0F0;
}
div.alert.alert-success {
  background-color: #2ECC71;
  border-color: #27AE60;
}
div.alert.alert-info {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  border-color: #2980B9;
}
div.alert.alert-warning {
  background-color: #E67E22;
  border-color: #D35400;
}
div.alert.alert-danger {
  background-color: #E74C3C;
  border-color: #C0392B;
}
div.alert.alert-posion {
  background-color: #9B59B6;
  border-color: #8E44AD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert">
  <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-shield"></i> Welcome to 099</p>
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-close"></i>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-info">
  <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-twitch"></i> Connect with Twitch</p>
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-close"></i>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-posion">
  <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-twitch"></i> Connecting to Twitch</p>
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-close"></i>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-success">
  <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> Successfully Logged In</p>
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-close"></i>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-warning">
  <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-exclamation"></i> Incorrect Password</p>
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-close"></i>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger">
  <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-close"></i> Unable to verify Account</p>
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-close"></i>
</div>
```

Note: This uses `FontAwesome` for their icons. The reason why I am using `$(document).on('click', 'div.alert > i'...` is because some of the alerts will be loaded in.

Is the jQuery *as compact as possible* or can it be compacted even more? (ignore the variables, I mean the actual animation code)

Comment: you could save six characters by using camel case for css names, eg, `paddingTop` instead of `'padding-top'` and `paddingBottom` instead of `'padding-bottom'` plus it's more consistent.

Comment: @jorjordandan, Nice! I didn't know about this.